# add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" added the web.config but i dont want it to get applied to jsBundle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using below entry in web.config:

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
```

but i dont want it to get applied to jsBundle because it should get added to local cache of browser. currently because of this header getting added to jsbundle response also, it is getting download after every postback.

Comment: Where exactly you're adding those headers in your `Web.config`?

Comment: Added it in    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         ...........................................................here.
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>